# Is there a way like -Wl,--whole-archive to force .so libs to load like .a libs in gcc?

Tags: gcc, .so

I have a lib that registers a callback with the main code. Unfortunately, that means that the lib does not get pulled in unless something else is referenced in the library. I used the -Wl,--whole-archive to fix this in the .a version of the library. Unfortunately it does not appear to work on .so libs. The lib modifies the function of the main code whether or not the main code knows the lib is present, so the lib is or is not added in the link depending on if its functionality is wanted.

Comment: So one workaround I tried that worked, is to reference the .so library in another, short .c file and include that in the link. This forces inclusion. It works, but it is ugly.

Comment: You could try marking one of the library functions as undefined, with [`-Wl,--require-defined,LIB_FUNCTION`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-defined-symbol).

Answer (score 0):

This is what `-Wl,--no-as-needed` is for. Also see [documentation for push-state option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-push-state-governing-input-file-handling), which shows how to use its `--as-needed` counterpart safely (request as-needed linking for two libraries on the command line without changing previous behavior for libraries that follow).

Comment: Apologies on the time for this one, I need to test it. Will get back to it.